# What is effectively continuous?

Tags: definition, computability

In Soare's book Recursively Enumerable Sets and Degrees I saw a sentence:

> $\Phi_e$ is an effectively continuous functional from the Cantor space $2^\omega$ to itself.

What does it mean for a function to be *effectively continuous*?

Comment: There's a definition here, on the second page: http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0885064X06000458/1-s2.0-S0885064X06000458-main.pdf?_tid=60eae2a8-6e7f-11e4-944b-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1416245589_87c03cff26d9e0383c9bba842b14a2ba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cantor space, $2^{\omega}$, is equipped with the product topology; the set $2=\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology. This topology is generated by the so-called cylinder sets $[\sigma]= \{x \in 2^\omega : x \succ \sigma\}$, where $\sigma$ is a finite binary string.

So a set is open if it is a union of cylinders. A set is called *effectively open* if it is a union of a c.e. set of cylinders.

A function $f:2^{\omega} \to 2^{\omega}$ is *effectively continuous* if $f^{-1}[\sigma]$ is effectively open for every finite string $\sigma$, and uniformly so; i.e. there is a single algorithm that when given $\sigma$, enumerates $f^{-1}[\sigma]$.

Let me know if you'd like more detail.

Answer (score 0):

By Alex R.'s link the adapted definition is as follows. Let $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real valued function. Let $A_F=\{(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{Q} : F([a,b]) \subseteq (c,d) \cap \mathbb{Q}\}$. Then $F$ is *effectively continuous* iff $A_F \in \Sigma_1$ (computably enumerable) and $\forall r \in \mathbb{R} \cap \Delta_0$ (computable real number) $\forall \epsilon > 0. \exists (a,b,c,d) \in A_F. a < x < b \land |d - c| \le \epsilon$.